# preference not taking effect

Tags: java, android, onesignal

I am trying notification on/off in one of my application. I have used preference checkbox for it. 
I am using this code in my main activity.

```
OneSignal.startInit(this).init();
    if(!AppPreference.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).isNotificationEnabled()) OneSignal.setSubscription(true);
    else OneSignal.setSubscription(false);
```

I have also tried this code in my application class, but its not taking instant effect as soon as I check checkbox as well uncheck checkbox, its taking effect after I open application two-three time, anyone know what is issue in it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calls to `OneSignal.setSubscription` are remembered by the SDK. You only need to make these calls from the check/uncheck event from your preference Activity.